# Can we use PHP inbuilt function inside Twig File in Symfony

Tags: symfony, twig

Hi Can anyone Please let me know can we use php inbuilt function inside a twig file.if not then why.
What is the way then to access php inbuilt function inside a twig file.

Because in a application in 100 of time we need to check many conditions basis of php inbuilt function.I have tried in_array() function to check multiple vaslue selected in a multiple dropdown  list but i am getting error Is_array() not defined.

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @DonCallisto Said, There is some PHP equivalent function exists in twig not all. So you cant call a php function from twig template. You may have to use a existing equivalent or need to create [one](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#functions) if not exists.

### **Why?**

One of the main reason is [SoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). Template is for presentation layer of your application. So twig made available tools(filter,functions, global variables) to do that.

### **Know the differences**

Though you have date function in twig. its not the same date function you have in php. To achieve a similar functionality you may have to use same or different approach in twig then php. for instance you can achieve php's in_array functionality using the twig's [Containment Operator](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#containment-operator)

### **What is the way**

Now come to last part of your question:

> What is the way then to access php inbuilt function inside a twig file?

I think you already know the short answer from @DonCallisto. You can create your [own extension](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#extending-twig). And define what function you needed. Or if you are crazy enough to access all php builtin function from your template, you can use this [Extension](http://pastebin.com/VZzgSGLq). It will allow you to call any php functions by prefixed with **php_**. for example if you like to call **in_array** function, then you can call like **php_in_array()** from your template.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Twig have some php builtin functions equivalent. For instance `in_array()` php function is `in` twig function. [Check it out](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#containment-operator)

If you don't find some builtin, you need to write your own [twig exstension](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#extending-twig)

Comment: Thanks there is In function which we can use as in_array() of php in twig file.

Comment: @user3458514: told you :) there is and is linked above